# HttpUrlConnection causing app to crash

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm a beginner android developer and currently developing a restaurant queue system. I've set up a php page that echoes the 'key' to be called, I'm trying to read this page, but my app always crashes when I call the function.

I have already added the internet permission in the android manifest.

The main activity code is this:

```
package com.example.mrdias.geradorsenha;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText campoNome, campoEspecial;
    TextView textoNome, textoSenha;
    Button botaoSenha;
    String nome, especial;
    String contador;
    String vazio = "";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        campoNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoNome);
        campoEspecial = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoEspecial);
        botaoSenha = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoSenha);
        textoNome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mostrarNome);
        textoSenha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mostrarSenha);


    }


    public void adicionarNomes (View view){
        nome = campoNome.getText().toString();
        especial = campoEspecial.getText().toString();
        textoNome.setText(nome);
        textoSenha.setText(especial);

        String method = "registro";

        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method, nome, especial);

    }

    public void gerasenha (View view){
        GeraSenha gerasenha = new GeraSenha();
        gerasenha.execute();
        contador = gerasenha.s;
    }
}
```

The GeraSenha.java is like this:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Mr. Dias on 25/09/2017.
 */

public class GeraSenha extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String s;
    TextView textoSenha;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        textoSenha.findViewById(R.id.mostrarSenha);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.mrdiasfotografia.com.br/mysql/gerarsenha.php");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection mUrlConnection = null;
        try {
            mUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);

        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(mUrlConnection.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            mUrlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        s = String.valueOf(is);
        return s;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textoSenha.setText(result);
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

---

So... I fixed the textview problem but right now what i get from it is this "com.example.mrdias.geradorsenha.gerasenha@8963a1" any ideas?

Comment: can you post your error logs here

Comment: Search in the logCat for exceptions. maybe the URL is not reachable.

Comment: At what line your app is crashing? What is the crash log

Comment: I guess there is not a case of down voting. New learners often make these mistakes and they don't even know

Comment: Sorry if my ignorance offended some of you. Don't know how generate post crash logs yet (yes, I'm a noob), will learn and post here.

@AbdulWaheed thanks for the help and support.

Answer (score 0):

```
on preExecute method 
textoSenha variable is null;

textoSenha.findViewById(R.id.mostrarSenha);
```

it will get NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
 @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    textoSenha.findViewById(R.id.mostrarSenha);
}
```

With below code

```
 @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    textoSenha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mostrarSenha);
}
```

Comment: I get a "Error:(23, 33) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)"

Shoud it be onPost Execute than?

Comment: hmm ok... can try passing the reference of the textview in constructor of GeraSenha  class. I am Assuming your textview is in MainActivity. Is that right

Comment: Yes they are, I'm using one activity at the moment, trying to build the functionality. First time using HttpURLConnect. Will try and post if it worked

Comment: So...

I fixed the textview problem but right now what i get from it is this "com.example.mrdias.geradorsenha.gerasenha@8963a1"

any ideas?